# Is it possible to transfer Native-eth from wallet A to wallet B and transfer some erc20 token from wallet B to Wallet A in a single transaction?

Tags: solidity, transactions, erc-20, gas, erc-4337

Is it possible to transfer Native-eth  from wallet A to wallet B and transfer some  erc20 token from wallet B to Wallet A in a single transaction? Because Wallet B has zero native-eth and some some erc20 token in it  and I don't want to do two transactions( first sending eth from wallet A to B and transfer some erc20 token from Wallet B to Wallet A).
Note: Above contract is an old erc20 contract similar to USDT contract , hence it don't have any permit functionality and transfer function have a require condition ( caller has to be msg.sender)
Please share any tips to spare some gas...
1.Is there a way to pack these two transactions  into a single one?
2. Will the ERC 4337 bundler do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible. If wallet B is affected by a sweeper bot you could try flashbots, but they will be two separate transactions.